# Open SMPP Erlang Library

Tags: erlang, makefile, smpp

I am trying to compile oserl-3.2.3 but I am getting this error

```
:~/oserl/oserl$ make
erlc -Wall -I include -I .. -o ebin src/gen_esme_session.erl
src/gen_esme_session.erl:751: function concat_binary/1 undefined
src/gen_esme_session.erl:765: function concat_binary/1 undefined
make: *** [gen_esme_session.beam] Error 1
```

I have Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.0] installed on Ubuntu 12.04LTS. To me concat_binary/1 is an in built erlang function but why does make complain that it is an defined.

Comment: I first installed **common_lib-3.3.0** before i attempted to install oserl

Comment: Use the recommended Erlang Version to build and run this library

Answer (score 0):

Function `erlang:concat_binary/1` has been removed since Erlang R15 (late 2011).
You can either fix oserl yourself (concat_binary/1 could be replaced with list_to_binary/1) or try a newer fork such as [iamaleksey/oserl](https://github.com/iamaleksey/oserl) on Github.